# CakePHP ajax render to different view

Tags: php, cakephp

I am stuck in a problem working on my project in CakePHP.

This is my code:

```
function publish_link()
    {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) 
        {
            $items = $_POST['image_id'];
            $this->set('selected_list', $items);
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->render('publish');
            exit;
        }
    }


function publish($items = null) {

        $this->layout = 'box';

        if(!empty($this->data['User']))
        {
                    //some code
            }
}
```

Here the publish_link action is called using Ajax and it renders to a different view file publish.ctp.

It renders it and I could get set value selected_list correctly, but after this ctp is rendered, its controller action publish() gets called and blanks out the variable selected_list that was set from publish_link().

I cannot understand how to deal with this.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are trying to pass variable from one action to another action. Which is not really the way cakephp works.

To share variable among actions, you should encapsulate them in `beforeFilter()` function like

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if(!empty($_POST['image_id'])) {
        $items = $_POST['image_id'];
        $this->set('selected_list', $items);
    }
}
```